# Cannot identify local issuer

Tags: php, ssl, curl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm getting this error:

```
SSL problem: can't identify local issuer
```

once I call the function to save an image or retrieve user's Facebook image:

```
file_get_contents()
```

What I've done is:

- I have my website running on Azure *.azurewebsites.com
- I added my custom domain and ssl certificate which were both bought from GoDaddy
- I created Certificate Signing Request (CSR) (which GoDaddy asked for) using OpenSSL on my Mac
- Signed it with it and downloaded it to get .p7b file and .crt file
- I added the .crt file to Azure and everything works fine, my custom domain now has the lock beside it

So after those steps, logging in with Facebook got that error also so I did a temporary fix:

```
curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

This is not recommended of course, but it allows me to test the rest of the site. The error still occurred but only when invoking file_get_contents(). I've tried these fixes from what I've seen scouring around:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/cacert/cacert.pem");
```

But no dice. Can someone explain exactly what the error means and also to combat it? That'd be great. And also, this might be due to creating my Certificate Signing Request with OpenSSL... not sure. Please confirm.

Comment: Why are you using ssl pem when you fetch file? why not use https:// it's supposed to already be installed on the server. I'm wondering why you're doing it this way?

Comment: So I'm using Parse Server PHP SDK, I just put curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/cacert/cacert.pem"); in ParseClient.php, when I fetch file, I'm doing file_get_contents( $_FILES['userImg']['tmp_name'] ) or file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $user['id'] . '/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1')

Answer (score 0):

`curl_setopt` flags works only with handler you're passing to those calls. `file_get_contents` has no idea about any of `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` or `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` flags.

Change `file_get_contents` to curl calls.

Comment: so you want me to create another function to mimic file_get_contents?

Comment: Not create, use existing one.

Comment: can you elaborate a little further? I'm not that familiar with php and curl